# Как сделать такую конвертацию в C#?

Tags: c#

Есть такое число:

```
1.0,
```

Когда я привожу его в JSON (`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)`), в C# и беру его md5hash, он приводится с нулем.

Когда я паршу его на JS, JS убирает нули и значение выходит 1. Когда я делаю `JSON.stringify(data)` на JS, он хранит его как 1. И в итоге я получаю разный хеш.

Как на C# приводить такое к int, в том случае, если нет дробной части?

Пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

double a = 1.0;
Dictionary<string, object> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    {"key", a},
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyDictionary);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

TargetFramework: net472

Comment: В C# какой тип у этого числа: decimal, double, float?..

Comment: Тип в C#: double

Comment: Отлично, а зачем это всё? Показанный фрагмент - не число, а строка "1.0,", в этом месте смысл вопроса вообще теряется.

Comment: Дайте пример кода, как формируете объект, как сериализуете, как десерализуете в JS, и как и от чего вычисляете хэш, с чем и как именно сверяете. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). А вообще сериализовать надо без нуля, разберитесь с форматированием чисел в JSON.NET. `1.0` - это неверный результат, и как вы уже догадались, несовместимый с JS.

Comment: Обновил, нужно вместо такого `{"key":1.0}` получить такое `{"key":1}`. Но если там, `{"key":1.2}` то, так `{"key":1.2}`. Как у JS.

Comment: Решил так, но это жуть: `string serializePattern = @"(\d)\.0";
            string replaced = Regex.Replace(serializedEntity, serializePattern, "$1");`